# Package Manager Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Acabo de intalar twpr y superSu Pro en una tablet lenovo A3300-vh estoy desarrollando una app con android studio y quise probarlar en la tablet pero me salta el siguiente error. Cuando elimino a superSu por completo quitando el root si me deja probar la app en la tablet sin ningun problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese error aparece normalmente cuando la aplicación que estas intentando ejecutar ya se encuentra instalada en tu dispositivo. Deberías revisar que el nombre de paquete de tu aplicación no coincida con el nombre de paquete de alguna aplicación que tengas instalada en el dispositivo.

Comment: no el problema ocurre cuando instalo supersu el nombre del paquete de mi aplicacion es co.jcesar.fincareport

Answer (score 0):

**Este mensaje se muestra cuando se usa el emulador (Android Virtual Device), en realidad el emulador tuvo un error el cual desconecta el dispositivo.**

Debes reiniciar el emulador y volver a construir y subir el .apk nuevamente al emulador. Puedes simplemente cerrarlo y ejecutar nuevamente el proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ya realizaste lo anterior, simplemente da OK para que instalé el nuevo .apk construido.

---

Si usas un dispositivo real, desconectalo y conectalo nuevamente hasta que se muestre en:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

simplemente da OK para que instalé el nuevo .apk construido.

Comment: no es un emulador es una tablet real de marca lenovo A3300 7 pulgadas con android 4.4 con root de supersu

Comment: Desconectalo y conectalo, espera a que se muestre en Select Deployment Target, y sube nuevamente el .apk

Comment: reinicie el pc y la tablet y sigue mostrarndo el mismo error, desistale supersu por completo y si me deja instalar la app, pero necesito a supersu